# Assign Special Characters inside a String Array

Tags: java, android

Android 2.3.3 / Java

I have a `String[]` that is assigned with static values containing special characters like `√x²+y²` and so on. When I try to save the file, i get the following error, please refer to the image below. How do I get over this? Assigning these values statically is a must. Is there a way I can change the encoding of the java file and yet have other things remain the same.

Here is how I am trying to assign the values ::: For example...

```
commandNames = new String[] {"√x²+y²","√x²+y²","√x²+y²"};
```

[image]

Comment: use save as UTF-8 .. what is the problem?

Comment: Sorry guys.. Too naive.. Didn't think of it. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file have `utf-8` characters.There is no issue by saving it as **Save as UTF-8**

Click that **saveasUTF8** button

or

Change your file properties by

**Windows > Preferences > General > Content Types, set UTF-8** as the 
default encoding for all content types.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using this in jsp page then include meta tag in header of your jsp page and
specify your content format in meta tag

and if it are using it in servlet then set response type as
response.setContentType("");